# Cordova 2.7 prompt message appears on page load

Tags: javascript, cordova

I just upgraded a project from Cordova 2.6 to 2.7 due to a bug in 2.6 with localstorage on Android. Now, on pageload, I'm presented with this nicety, in 3 slightly different ways:

[image]

If I click OK, the page crashes. It appears its coming from this:

```
module.exports = {
  exec: function(service, action, callbackId, argsJson) {
    return prompt(argsJson, 'gap:'+JSON.stringify([service, action, callbackId]));
  },
  setNativeToJsBridgeMode: function(value) {
    prompt(value, 'gap_bridge_mode:');
  },
  retrieveJsMessages: function() {
    return prompt('', 'gap_poll:');
  }
};
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

**Edit:** It doesn't appear to happen on Android itself, but it does happen in Chrome, and this application works in both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should include the Cordova script in your Chrome only distribution. This alert is popping up because internally Cordova for Android uses the `alert()` mechanism to pass events between the JavaScript and Native code portions of a Cordova app. I'm pretty sure that when you view the app through Chrome, the rest of Cordova never really gets set up (the native portions), so the alert is not captured and instead is actually surfaced to the Chrome browser.

If the application you are developing works in both Chrome and Android (I'm assuming you are packaging it via Cordova into a native .apk?), I'm having a hard time understanding what you are using Cordova for... If you are not using any of the native device functionality that Cordova provides (Camera access, accelerometer, etc.) and are just using it to wrap a web app in a native shell, you might find it easier to just develop (for Chrome) and release the web app as...well, a web app.

Although I do think one of the major benefits of Cordova is much greater distribution potential in the form of native applications. If this is what you are planning on doing, then I'd say just ignore the alert while you test on Chrome. If you plan to release native apps (via Cordova) and the web app, just remove the Cordova script from the production version of the web app.

Comment: The app has additional functionality that is conditionally displayed or used (camera, gps, local storage for offline use) when packaged as cordova and on a mobile device versus when it's run in Chrome. It's a super big code-reuse benefit to share the bulk of the app between the two use-cases. I ended up just also conditionally loaded the cordova script, which was fine, but it was strange as this had never happened before that version (I've been developing cordova apps for about 2 years).